# Having trouble aggregating data that is first unioned and also inner joined

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I work in advertising and I am working with really large data in SQL Server Management Studio for my client who runs hundreds of millions of ad impressions in a week.

I need to compute an overlap analysis to determine how many times a user (GUIDN) is being reached across two different publisher sites.

The data was originally over 10GB+ and couldn't be imported into the same database/table due to size limits, so I imported the data into six different tables which exist in three different databases. There are three tables belonging to site A, and three tables belonging to site T.

To start, I want to look at the impressions served to each CAMPAIGN_NAME/SITENAME/PLACEMENT_NAME/GUIDN combination from site A (in aggregate across all A_Tables). Then, I want to map over all impressions from all T_Tables whose CAMPAIGN_NAME and GUIDN match using a LEFT JOIN.

e.g.

- In [DB2_Site].[dbo].[A_Table]:

  - Campaign A, Site B, Placement A, GUIDN A = 40 impressions
- In [DB2.1_Site].[dbo].[A_Table]:

  - Campaign A, Site B, Placement A, GUIDN A = 30 impressions
- In [DB2.2_Site].[dbo].[A_Table]:

  - Campaign A, Site B, Placement A, GUIDN A = 20 impressions
- In [DB2_Site].[dbo].[T_Table]:

  - Campaign A, Site B, Placement A, GUIDN A = 10 impressions
- In [DB2.1_Site].[dbo].[T_Table]:

  - Campaign A, Site B, Placement B, GUIDN A = 20 impressions
- In [DB2.2_Site].[dbo].[T_Table]:

  - Campaign A, Site B, Placement C, GUIDN A = 30 impressions

I want the result in the new [AT_Mapping] table to look like:
- Campaign A, Site B, Placement A, GUIDN A = 90 impressions, 60 impressions

WHERE: the 90 represents the impressions belonging to that CAMPAIGN_NAME/SITENAME/PLACEMENT_NAME/GUIDN combination from [A_Table], and the 60 represents the impressions belonging to that CAMPAIGN_NAME and GUIDN combination (in aggregate - SITENAME/PLACEMENTNAME should not be checked) from [T_Table].

Essentially, I want to "look at all data" while running the query, but the exported result will be much smaller compared to the combined size of the two tables I'm referencing since I will be looking at aggregate data.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  
    Z.[CAMPAIGN_NAME], 
    Z.[SITENAME], 
    Z.[PLACEMENT_NAME], 
    Z.[GUIDN], 
    SUM(Z.[TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED]) As A_Impressions, 
    SUM(IsNull(Y.[TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED], 0)) As T_Impressions,
    SUM(Z.[TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED] + IsNull(Y.[TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED], 0)) As Total_Impressions
INTO [DB2_Results].[dbo].[AT_Mapping]   
FROM (  
    SELECT [CAMPAIGN_NAME], [SITENAME], [PLACEMENT_NAME], [GUIDN], [TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED]
    FROM [DB2_Site].[dbo].[A_Table]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [CAMPAIGN_NAME], [SITENAME], [PLACEMENT_NAME], [GUIDN], [TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED]
    FROM [DB2.1_Site].[dbo].[A_Table]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [CAMPAIGN_NAME], [SITENAME], [PLACEMENT_NAME], [GUIDN], [TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED]
    FROM [DB2.2_Site].[dbo].[A_Table]
    ) As Z
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT [CAMPAIGN_NAME], [GUIDN], SUM([TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED]) AS TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED
    FROM [DB2_Site].[dbo].[T_Table]
    GROUP BY [CAMPAIGN_NAME],[GUIDN]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [CAMPAIGN_NAME], [GUIDN], SUM([TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED]) AS TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED
    FROM [DB2.1_Site].[dbo].[T_Table]
    GROUP BY [CAMPAIGN_NAME],[GUIDN]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [CAMPAIGN_NAME], [GUIDN], SUM([TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED]) AS TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED
    FROM [DB2.2_Site].[dbo].[T_Table]
    GROUP BY [CAMPAIGN_NAME],[GUIDN]
) As Y
ON Y.[GUIDN] = Z.[GUIDN] And Y.[CAMPAIGN_NAME] = Z.[CAMPAIGN_NAME]  
GROUP BY Z.[CAMPAIGN_NAME], Z.[SITENAME], Z.[PLACEMENT_NAME], Z.[GUIDN];
```

Note:

- Impressions = TOTAL_ADS_REQUESTED
- A_Table contains publisher A impression data
- T_Table contains publisher T impression data
- [DB2_Site], [DB2.1_Site], and [DB2.2_Site] are my databases. They each contain [A_Table] and [T_Table]
- Both tables contain the same columns and have the same data types.

The problem I'm running into is what when I run this query - I get more impressions than actually exist.

For instance, for GUID ABC, in [A_Table] there are 2 impressions and [T_Table] there are 6 impressions (manual check by filtering rows for this GUID). However, the result I'm getting after running the above query is that A_Impressions (which should represent impressions from the UNIONed A_Tables) is 6 while the T_Impressions (which should represent impressions from the UNIONed T_Tables) is 16.

It would appear that my result is somehow being duplicated or triplicated - but I'm not sure why. I first aggregated the data I needed from each table using GROUP BY and then did another GROUP BY after I joined the two UNIONed tables, but it's not working as I expected.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sample data and desired results, as tabular text, would help better understanding your question.

Comment: Is it possible that some of your data is duplicated? What happens if you change your `UNION ALL` to `UNION`?

Comment: My data shouldn't be duplicated... My log file that I pulled the data from had 130 million rows and I imported the data in groups of 1- 40,000,000 & 40,000,001 - 80,000,000 & 80,000,001 - 130,000,000.

Comment: I intentionally used UNION ALL because I wanted all rows from each table. There should be no duplicates across the tables since I didn't import overlapping rows.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for the records that you know are in error for each of the tables involved? We'll need something to go on.

Comment: You are joining impressions from A & T.  If the same campaign&guid appears 2 times in A and 3 times in T, the result of the (left) join  on campaign&guid will be 6 rows.

Comment: @lptr - Thank you. You might be on to something there. Is there any reason 6 rows would be created? My ideal output in that scenario would be 2 rows from A, followed by the aggregate total of impressions from T that match the GUIDN and CAMPAIGN_NAME from those rows.

Comment: I think what I want to do is union data -> aggregate data -> then join data. However, for some reason the data isn't being aggregated before the join, and so duplicates are occurring as you mentioned. Is there a way to aggregate unioned data within an inner join?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out! I had to wrap the T table in another select statement that aggregated the results with group by. Thanks for your help lptr! Couldn't have done it without your lead.

Comment: ..@user2946613 ..nice! this is one of the common troubles/pitfalls when aggregating on joins. once you figure it out, you own it and know how to deal with it in the future..